# Adding an additional step to ">>="

Tags: haskell

I have this which works fine:

```
forM_ [1..10] $ \x -> myFunc1 x 99 >>= putStrLn . show >> return ()

myFunc1 :: Int -> Int -> IO Bool
myFunc1 .....
```

I want to do add an additional string to the output:

```
   forM_ [1..10] $ \x -> myFunc1 x 99 >>= (++) "the result is: " >>= putStrLn . show >> return ()
```

But that doesn't compile. I've tried different variations but still no success. Your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compose `show` with the concatenation function like so:

```
forM_ [1..10] $ \x -> myFunc1 x 99 >>= putStrLn . ("the result is: " ++) . show >> return ()
```

Answer (score 7):

The first thing that sticks out is that the expression:

```
(++) "the result is: "
```

is not an IO-action - it's just a pure function String -> String, and
that's one reason why you code isn't type checking.

To turn it into an IO-action you can compose it with `return`:

```
return . ( (++) "the result is: " )
  :: String -> IO String
```

Now you can use it with `>>=`.

However, that's not where the real problem is...

To prepend "the result is: " before the `show` you have to insert it in the `putStrLn` call:

```
... >>= putStrLn . (++ "the result is: ") . show
```

(Note that there is no need to `>> return ()` since `putStrLn` already returns ()).

Honestly, this is a lot simpler using do-notation:

```
forM_ [1..10] $ \x -> do
  s <- myFunc1 x 99
  putStrLn $ "the result is: " ++ show s
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `++` with `add`

```
add x y = return (x ++ show (y))


forM_ [1..10] $ \x -> myFunc1 x 99 >>= add "the result is: " >>= putStrLn . show >> return ()
```

reason: The return type of `++` is not `IO` type

Comment: Your answer could be justifiably downvoted because of its lack of explanation and the irrelevance of `add`.